# How to handle errors in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception, toad

I'm currently a beginner at PL/SQL and am just learning and trying to absorb as much as I can. What I am currently tasked with doing is studying error handling for packages writtten in PLSQL. I'm having trouble understanding what these packages are doing and how to take care of the Exception/error handling for the scripts.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY APMS.customer IS

PROCEDURE customer_collateral_hist(i_Vcust_cd   IN customer_collateral_history.cust_cd%TYPE,
                                   i_Vfromdate  IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vtodate    IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vauthstat  IN customer_collateral_history.auth_stat%TYPE,
                                   o_Cresultset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_Cresultset FOR
     SELECT auth_stat,
            buld_size,
            clos_dt,
            cnfm_dt,
            cnfm_tm,
            cnfm_user_id,
            cust_cd,
            date_seq,
            dbtr,
            dbtr_addr,
            dbtr_id,
            dbtr_tel_no,
            dbtr_zip_cd1,
            dbtr_zip_cd2,
            esta_orga,
            grnt_dt_from,
            grnt_dt_to,
            jdg_amt,
            jdg_dt,
            land_size,
            loc_addr,
            mort_amt,
            mort_chng_dt,
            mort_flag,
            mort_max_amt,
            mort_seq,
            mort_stat,
            old_key,
            ownr,
            ownr_addr,
            ownr_id,
            ownr_tel_no,
            ownr_zip_cd1,
            ownr_zip_cd2,
            prev_mort_amt,
            redm_dt,
            reg_dt,
            reg_dttm,
            reg_flag,
            reg_user_id,
            remark,
            supr_pow_flag
       FROM customer_collateral_history
      WHERE cust_cd LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vcust_cd, cust_cd)||'%'
        AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) >= NVL(i_Vfromdate,   TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) <= NVL(i_Vtodate, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND auth_stat LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vauthstat, auth_stat)||'%';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       NULL;
END customer_collateral_hist;

END customer;
/
```

This is a package body I am looking at. Would anybody be willing to help me out on how I would handle the errors for this script> The current exception is not sufficient. This much I know.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not all of your code is in the code block. Could you indent it one more level?

Comment: I'd simply remove the exception handler entirely.  Handle the exceptions that you realistically can, let the rest propagate up to the caller.  Maybe it would make sense to catch the exception, log the exception to a table, and then re-throw the exception.  But as a first step, I'd just get rid of any exception handler where you're not able to do something specific to handle a specific error.

Comment: I'm sorry like I said I am new to PLSQL. my mentor/superior tasked me with error handling in all the packages, this being one of them. Why would this not have an exception handler? Shouldn't all packages have an exception/error handler?

Comment: `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;` is equal to "No matter what happens, just ignore it." I think such behavior you like to have only in very rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- handle exception
```

The clause OTHERS catches every exception that you didn't already handle

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        -- handle no data found
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- handle other exceptions
```

This handles NO_DATA_FOUND first and all the other posible exceptions in the OTHERS case. You can handle as much as you can

To define your own exception you do:

```
DEFINE
    your_exception EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    your_queries;
    RAISE your_exception
EXCEPTION
    WHEN your_exception THEN
        your_handle
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect some people may comment, but if I were writing that procedure, I would not have an exception handler at all.

A few pointers for exception handling.

First, only use exception handlers for situations that you reasonably expect and can do something about.

For example, if you are doing a `SELECT..INTO` and know that it is legimate that there be no data found or too many rows, then handle them and code what you would like to do in each situation.  Maybe, use a default value in the case of no_data_found.

Second, do NOT code a `WHEN OTHERS` handler if all you are going to do is log it and then re-raise it to the caller.  As a general rule, you should let true exceptions (those you don't reasonably expect and handle) propagate back to the caller.

It is easy to write code that "never fails", if all you mean by that is that it never throws an error.  That is not the same thing as writing robust code.

In your particular case, there are no reasonable exceptions to expect.  Anything weird that happens should go to the caller to handle.  There is no point in catching an exception you cannot do anything about.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone here is helping a great deal. I'm just new to this. I've done basic database design in college but PLSQL is very difficult to grasp. I was told to do error handling on the procedures bu they all have that same exception handle. Arghh I need to learn this stuff.